# Spring annotations are not working in IBM mobile First V 7.1.0

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, adapter, spring-annotations

I tried to use inbuilt Spring Annotations in adapters. Basically I tried @Autowired.

I guess the bean is not getting registered.Are there any configurations involved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adapters in MFP are not working with spring OOTB. Therefore, @Autowire and all those kind of annotations are not expected to work.

However, if you consider migration to MFP 8.0.0, you can integrate spring into your adapter and then @Autowire will work.

See the blog: https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/blog/2016/04/24/MobileFirst-spring-integration-in-java-adapters/

Comment: Thanks. MF7 and MF8 altogether looks different with setup and configurations. MF 8 provides better interface to use maven and springs.